# How does reading of objects from a boost archive work that have been stored via pointers to base class?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I'm trying to understand how boost handles the serialization of objects that are stored via pointers to a base class. Especially how the subsequent reading from a thus created archive works. Here's some example code (omitting the inclusion of all the headers):

```
class A
{
  public:
    A() {};
    ~A() {};
    virtual void dummy() {};
  private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) {};
};

class B : public A
{
  public:
    B() : x(0) {};
    B( int _x ) : x(_x) {};
    ~B() {};
    void dummy() {}; 
    int x;
  private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
      ar & boost::serialization::base_object<A>(*this);
      ar & x;
    }
};

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT( B )
BOOST_CLASS_IMPLEMENTATION( B, boost::serialization::object_serializable)
BOOST_CLASS_TRACKING( B, boost::serialization::track_never)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  { //writing the archive
    boost::filesystem::ofstream file( "archive.dat", std::ios::trunc );
    boost::archive::text_oarchive archive( file );

    A* ptr = new B(3);
    archive & ptr;
  }

  { // reading the archive
    boost::filesystem::ifstream file( "archive.dat" );
    boost::archive::text_iarchive archive( file );

    /** What is supposed to go here? */
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I figured that

```
A* ptr;
archive & ptr;
```

somehow seems to do the job for the readout section. But how does it work? Does it first create an object of type `B` on the heap using the standard constructor (as this seems to be required) and later sets the values of the internal members?

Are there alternatives? For example, can I directly instantiate an object of type `B` from the archive if I know that the archive only contains objects of type `B` (though serialized through base class pointers)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is working off of a partial template specialization for pointer types. Somewhere in boost is something of the sort:

```
class text_oarchive {
    template <class T> operator&(T);
};
```

and then there's a specialization:

```
template <class T*>
text_oarchive<T*>::operator&(T *t) {
    //serial the value as a pointer
}
```

You could test to see if it's creating a copy of B on the heap by making a class without a default constructor.

Comment: No, it doesn't work without a standard constructor. It fails in access.hpp in `static void construct(T * t){ ::new(t)T; }`. According to http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#constructors it invokes the constructor "in-place" - what does this mean? In order to get by without a default constructor one apparently would have to overload the save/load routines.